# Error While Installing IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility

Tags: windows-7, iis-6

While I'm installing the IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility, I got an error as below, Please any one have idea about it?
**[IIS Error Message]**

[image: IIS Error Message]

**Machine Configuration:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you catch any logs in eventvwr.msc? (Event Viewer)

It is possible that the source of the package is corrupted